# Sub query not allowed in Stored procedure error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a procedure but getting an error in the below part of the procedure.

Getting the below errors:

> PL/SQL: Statement ignored ERROR PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in
>   PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
>   this context  ERROR

The code is:

```
   --DECLARE
   L_ERROR_POINT   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   P_STATUS_CODE := 0;
   P_ERROR_MESSAGE := '';

   --My error occurs in the below two lines--

   IF(P_DE || ' A' = (SELECT DAL_ET.PARAMETER_DESC FROM DAL_ET) 
   AND P_IDENTIFIER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION =(SELECT DAL_ET.PARAMETER_TEXT_VALUE FROM DAL_ET))

   THEN

   L_ERROR_POINT := 'INSERT INTO DAL_ID_TB';
```

How can i rewrite this query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain it pls?

Comment: @KevinEsche There is `||` in Oracle, it means concatenate.

Comment: Exactly i have used || before and it has worked fine. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

Comment: @TonyAndrews you´re so right... my bad. jumping between programming languages doesn´t end well. But still a select in the `if` isn´t valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a query directly within an `IF` statement; to get what you need, you can use a variable:

```
DECLARE
  vCheckValue varchar2(100);
  ...
BEGIN
  select ...
  into vCheckValue 
  from ...
  where ...
  --
  if (vCheckValue  = ...) then
     ...
  end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following into variables:

```
SELECT DAL_ET.PARAMETER_DESC
into   v_PARAMETER_DESC
FROM DAL_ET

SELECT DAL_ET.PARAMETER_TEXT_VALUE
into   v_PARAMETER_TEXT_VALUE
```

and use them in the if statement:

```
IF(P_DE || ' A' = v_PARAMETER_DESC
AND P_IDENTIFIER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = v_PARAMETER_TEXT_VALUE)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a SQL statement within an `IF` condition.  Instead you must run the SQL statement first, save the result into a variable, and use that in the `IF`:

```
SELECT DAL_ET.PARAMETER_DESC 
  INTO l_param_desc
  FROM DAL_ET;

IF l_param_desc = P_DE || ' A' 
AND ...
```